# "Could not update ICEauthority file..." error

Tags: linux, fedora, omnet++, fedora16

I have fedora16 on my computer and omnet++ 4.2.1.

I just installed omnet++ 4.2.2.

when I restart my system from now I am unable to login as my user name.

Fedora is giving me this error message : Could not update ICEauthority file/home... .ICEauthority.

It leaves me at the desktop background without access to anything.

Any suggestion for this error would be appreciated.

Comment: hi can u please help me .. i am also getting same issue .

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because of permission errors. When the error pops up, Try this:

1) switch to a new virtual terminal `ctrl alt F2` and login

2) sudo chown username ./ -R

That solved the problem for me.

Comment: by the way, login with your username only, no the root